# Vue form @submit.prevent does not work in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a Vue 3 component (a Nuxt 3 environment) with just a simple form which I am trying to prevent the default behavior of reloading the page. As many times in other Vue projects I am using `@submit.prevent` on the form element which works as expected on desktop. However, to my big surprise this does **not** work in neither iOS (Safari/Chrome) nor Android (Chrome). On mobile when either pressing the button or pressing 'Enter/Return' the page reloads. I have tried everything, for example tried manually calling `event.preventDefault()` and calling `@submit.prevent.stop` but with no success.

Below is the component code:

```
<template>
  <div class="login">
    <h1>Log in</h1>

    <form class="login-form" @submit.prevent="login()" id="form">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" v-model="email" />
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" v-model="password" />

      <button type="submit" id="submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const email = ref("");
const password = ref("");

async function login() {
  // Login logic
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

If anyone has any insight into this please share, and thank you in advance.

Comment: May I ask how you test it on mobile? I made a test and it is working just fine.

Comment: @ReaganM I use Vite with npm run nuxt dev and the local network ip address on port 3000, in my case 192.168.1.190:3000. The project is a bit larger than this component, but I don't think it should affect this in any way. I might be wrong though but am clueless where to look.

Comment: I did the same with ios chrome and it is working fine for me :)

Comment: @ReaganM Yeah, it is really strange for me. I don’t really know where to debug further

Comment: @RasmusLian quick demo. works on iOS 16. luck? https://play.vuejs.org/#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

Comment: @jjj This demo works as expected, no page reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Solved my issue, it was due to an error with communicating with the database server. It tried to fetch that at localhost on the phone, but it should have been the 192.168.1.190 address instead. For future people reading this try to see if any errors are causing this problem, thank you @asdofindia for the tip!

Comment: If a particular answer has been significantly instrumental in answering the question the recommended action is to suggest any potential improvements to that answer (if necessary) and mark it as the correct one, rather than posting a brand new answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your application bundle is large, make sure the page has finished loading fully before you try clicking login. I can reproduce your issue *while* the JavaScript is still loading because the @submit.prevent is not evaluated till the JavaScript has finished loading and running. But once the page fully loads the default HTML behavior is overridden.

This is possibly why you're unable to reproduce the issue with jjj's playground demo and others are unable to reproduce your issue either.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestions, however this is not the case in my situation. I've tried waiting and still same result.

Comment: Try connecting a debugger so you can see the console if any JavaScript has errored https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/ @RasmusLian

Comment: Great tip! This helped my find my issue, it was due to an error in fetching data from my database at localhost, needed to change localhost to 192.168.1.190 so that it fetched from there and not on the phone's localhost!

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried `stop` for *stopPropergation*.

If find myself doing `@submit.prevent.stop=""` in some cases.

I'm not sure why `preventDefault` is not enough on it's own in some cases.

It should stop a page reload, perhaps it's a browser bug, maybe it's caused by a plugin, could be some form of nested relaying of original event bubbling up in nested function calls in which case `stop` would... well stop it...

Comment: Yes I have tried this unfortunately without any luck.